# EXIFJS, getdata callback function never calls in React-bootstrap (5) Typescript module

Tags: logging, bootstrap-5, exif, react-tsx, exif-js

I'm basically using code directly from the exif-js documentation as can be seen here:

```
var img2 = document.getElementById("img2");
EXIF.getData(img2, function(this: any) {
    var allMetaData = EXIF.getAllTags(this);
    console.log(allMetaData);
});
```

I never get the console prints. I've implemented a solution with exifr like this:

```
const getExif = async () => {
        //console.log('test')
    var img1: any = document.getElementById("imageForExif") || "";
   
    if(img1 !== "") {
        let metadata = await exifr.parse(img1)
        console.log(metadata)
    }
        
}
```

Which works beautifully. But I would still like to figure out why the exif-js solution never goes into the callback function.

I'm calling the getExif function from a useEffect that triggers on image upload.

I am expecting the EXIF.getData operation to enter the callback and print the exif data.